Problems with update Dataverse lookup column using java 8
I have a problems and can't update lookup column using java. I tested several variants but nothing was working. Follow is the code (same code I am using for other types of columns and it is working there):
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    DataverseController.updateColumnEMailMVPLookup(
        "/tableWithDataForInput(GUID_of_row)", 
        "GUID_row_id_in_table_for_change", 
        token, 
        "https://myOrganiztion.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/", 
        "uniqa_mailtype"
    );
}

public static void updateColumnEMailMVPLookup(
    String value, 
    String row_id, 
    String token, 
    String url, 
    String columnForEditting
) throws IOException {
    
    Map<String, Object> mapUpdate = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    if ((value != null) && (value.trim().length() > 0)) {            
        mapUpdate.put(columnForEditting + "@odata.bind", "/" + value);    
    }
    
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mapUpdate);
    String jsonString = obj.toString();
    
    String uri = url + "nameTableForCorrect(" + row_id + ")";
    
    URL urlFinal = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlFinal.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT"); // PATCH back error
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    
    try (OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()) {
        outputStream.write(jsonString.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    
    int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT) {
        // Successful update, no content expected in response
        System.out.println("Update successful.");
    } else {
        // Read the error response
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getErrorStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Update failed: " + responseCode + " " + httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
        System.err.println("Error response: " + response.toString());
        String enf = "";
    }
}

If somebody can help with this I will be very thankful.
I tried a lot. Really the problem is that it do not accept manner of writing lookup column.
Error:
Update failed: 400 Bad Request
Error response: {"error":{"code":"0x80048d19","message":"Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293  ---->  InnerException : Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'uniqa_mailtype' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadUndeclaredProperty(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName, Boolean propertyWithValue)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadPropertyWithoutValue(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ReadResourceContent>b__0(PropertyParsingResult propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func`2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadResourceContent(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.StartReadingResource()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceSetItemStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementationSynchronously(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.CrmODataEntityDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)."}}


I have no experience with Dataverse but from the minimal research that I just did, I understand that you need some Java library to enable you to use the Dataverse API. If that is correct, then I suggest that you [edit] your question and indicate which library you are using. I think you should also indicate which JSON library you are using. And by the way (and not directly related to your question), I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help].

@Abra the user is doing a standard REST API call and as he wrote he is able to update other fields. Vlad please check my tool Dataverse REST Builder, it can give you the right syntax for the columnForEditting and value variables you have there
